# Magento 2 Redis Deprecated Functionality Causing Magento not to Start

Tags: magento2, error, cache, redis

Magento 2 is failing to start. The logs show this error:

> Deprecated Functionality: implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters in vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php on line 1414

[Also](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

> Implode with historical parameter order: Passing parameters to implode() in reverse order is deprecated, use implode($glue, $parts) instead of implode($parts, $glue).

I have a standard Redis installation and this is part of it (although I did not install it directly):
https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession

There is **no custom code** in the site. Redis was installed in the usual way according to these [Magento Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/redis/redis-pg-cache.html).

Here's the code referenced by the error message:

```
   1406     /**
   1407      * Build the Redis unified protocol command
   1408      *
   1409      * @param array $args
   1410      * @return string
   1411      */
   1412     private static function _prepare_command($args)
   1413     {
   1414         return sprintf('*%d%s%s%s', count($args), CRLF, implode(array_map(array('self', '_map'), $args), CRLF), CRLF);
   1415     }
```

**Has anyone run into this error yet?** Is there a solution (other than disabling Redis)?

Version info:

- Magento ver. 2.3.3
- redis 5.0.7
- redis-cli 5.0.7

EDIT: I opened an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_RedisSession/issues/172).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento 2.3.3 is not compatible with PHP 7.4.

Please downgrade your PHP version to 7.3.x to resolve this issue

Comment: I can downgrade to PHP 7.2